# How to use the FedAuth cookie in 'ClientContext'

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, authentication

We have to access a SharePoint site using FedAuth. We have the code which gets us the FedAuth cookie. What we are unable to get is how we would be using this FedAuth cookie in our `ClientContext` object.

Below is the code snippet.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {

 string siteUrl = "<SHAREPOINT SITE>";

 ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
 clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest;
 //clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Anonymous;
 clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web);
 clientContext.RequestTimeout = 720000;
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

 Console.WriteLine("Name of the web is: " + clientContext.Web.Title);


}

static void clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest(object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e) {
 e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.CookieContainer = getCookieContainer(); // Get FedAuth cookie
 e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
}
```

The method `getCookieContainer()` gets the FedAuthCookie. The request always times out (`Web Exception has Caught. The operation has timed out`) but no kind of authorization exception is thrown.

How can we access the SharePoint site with FedAuth cookie?

Comment: Are you on-premise? Which kind of authentication you are trying to achieve? ADFS with username\password or something else?

Comment: @Kai: On premise. We are using ADFS but for credentials we are sending default network credentials.

Comment: @Naveen, I have exactly same objective as yours - using default network credential to perform ADFS auth to a sharepoint site. I would like to know how is your getCookieContainer() being implemented. Could you please post the code for completeness? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were finally able to fix the issue. The problem was that the method `getCookieContainer()` was asynchronously calling methods to get FedAuth cookie. So rather than writing like this:

```
static void clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest(object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e) {
 e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.CookieContainer = getCookieContainer(); // Get FedAuth cookie
 e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
}
```

We called the method `getCookieContainer()` and stored it in an object and then assigned it in `ExecutingWebRequest`.

```
static void clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest(object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e) {
 e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieObj; // Store value returned from getCookieContainer() and then use it.
 e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For that purpose I would strongly recommend you to use PnP `AuthenticationManager` class, which already contains methods for obtaining `ClientContext` with different authentication mechanism.
For example for your requirements there are

`public ClientContext GetADFSUserNameMixedAuthenticatedContext`
`public ClientContext GetNetworkCredentialAuthenticatedContext`

How to use:

- Install PnP from nuget `Install-Package SharePointPnPCore2013`
- Use any of the `AuthenticationManager` methods listed above

Each methods returns `ClientContext` bound to user.

Links:
[authenticate-sharepoint-using-pnp-authentication-manager](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/authenticate-sharepoint-using-pnp-authentication-manager/)
[Introduction-to-authentication-manager-in-pnp-core-library](https://dev.office.com/blogs/Introduction-to-authentication-manager-in-pnp-core-library)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. We were able to fix the issue (see answer).

Answer (score 2):

```
ClientContext cc = new ClientContext(spSiteUrl);
cc.ExecutingWebRequest += (object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e) =>
{
    e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = "FedAuth=" + _fedAuth + ";rtFa=" + _rtFa;
};
```